# Stacking JPanels on top of other

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I have created 5 very similar panels that are suppuosed to be visible in the same area of a frame on at a time, What I mean is that when the app stars one of them (JPanel0) is visible and the other four are created but invisible and when i hit Button1, JPanel1 sets to visible and JPanel0 goes invisible, same with all.

I manage to get close with the BorderLayout But I cant get all of them to be centered in what would be the center position. Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

Could [`CardLayout`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) be what you may be looking for?

[The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html) has an article on [How to Use CardLayout](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), which includes an example which switches between a couple of `JPanel`s which get swapped by using `CardLayout`.

Comment: beat me to it, +1

CardLayout is IMO exactly what Ignacio is looking for

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use OverlayLayout.